# How to fill 128 boxes with 8 different code from mid of the row using program

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort, divide-and-conquer

I want to fill the 128 boxes with different no. of colors.

Let's consider that I have 8 colors to fillup those boxes and please check the below visual representation for an expected output.

[image]

I've tried by using the Javascript, but didn't get the expected result,

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var res = ''
    ,   order = {}
    ,   levels = {'#': 'red', '&': '#009688', 'O': '#FF9800', '@': '#FFEB3B', '%': '#9C27B0', '*': '#2196F3', '^': '#00BCD4', '-': '#FF9800'}
    ,   symbols = Object.keys(levels)
    ,   totalLevels = symbols.length;


    for (i=0; i < 128; i++) { order[i+1] = ' ';  }
    var ids = '';
    for (v=1; v <= 8; v++) {
        var level = v;
        var times = Math.ceil(128/level);
        ids += 'Level ' + level + ' (Times: '+ times + ') : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

        console.log(times);
        for (i=1; i <= times; i++) {
            var idx = i * (times-1);
            if (idx <= 128) {
                order[idx] = symbols[level-1];
                ids += (idx-1) + ', ';
            }
        }

        ids += '<br />';
    }

    var row1 = '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
    ,   row2 = '<td class="header red">Symbol</td>'
    Object.entries(order).map(function(item, i) {
        var symbol = item[1]
        ,   color  = symbol != ' ' ? levels[symbol] : '';

        row1 += '<td style="font-weight: bold;">'+ item[0] + '</td>';
        row2 += '<td style="'+ (color != '' ? 'background: '+ color +'; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;' : '') +'">'+ symbol + '</td>';
    });


    // Color bar
    bar = '<div id="color-bar">';
    Object.entries(levels).map(function(item, i) {
        bar += '<div class="code" style="background: '+ item[1] +'">'+ item[0] +'</div>';
    });

    bar += '<div>'+ ids + '</div>';
    bar += '</div>';

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = bar +'<table><tr>' + row1 + '</tr><tr>' + row2 + '</tr></table>';
}
```

```css
table {
    margin-top: 20%;
}
td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
    border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.header {
    background: #eee;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.red {
    background: #f33;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#color-bar {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}

#color-bar .code {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
        <div id="result"></div>
```

Looks like the logic is not correct!, Please correct me if anything wrong. Thanks,

I'm deeply looking for the logic only. Any programming language is fine for me. (C/C++, Python, PHP, JAVA, Javascript, even shell script!)

Comment: Why is the middle of 1..128 equal to 64? I mean, 1..128 has an even number of values, so there is no middle element. 65 is just as middle as 64...

Comment: @trincot There is no strict rules. If `n==0` then mid should be either `n += 1` or `n -= 1`. Would be fine if we're doing the same for an all levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula does not match your description:

```
 Math.ceil(128/level);
```

because you describe powers of two (64, 32, ...), but here you get results like 128/3 = 43.

Although not an *exact* match (see my comment below your question), you could count the number of trailing zeroes in the binary representation of the number, and start counting from zero (so 0..127):

| decimal | 7-bit binary | # trailing zeroes | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0000000 | 7 | red |
| 1 | 0000001 | 0 | gray |
| 2 | 0000010 | 1 | purple |
| 3 | 0000011 | 0 | gray |
| 4 | 0000100 | 2 | orange |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8 | 0001000 | 3 | cyan |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 16 | 0010000 | 4 | yellow |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 32 | 0100000 | 5 | blue |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 64 | 1000000 | 6 | green |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 127 | 1111111 | 0 | gray |
| 128 | 0000000 | 7 | red |

So then the algorithm can be a bit-checking one:

```js
let colors = ["gray", "purple", "orange", "cyan", "yellow", "blue", "green", "red"];
let container = document.getElementById("content");
for (let i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
    let zeroes = Math.min(7, 31 - Math.clz32(i ^(i-1)));
    let color = colors[zeroes];
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = i;
    div.style.background = color;
    container.appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#content div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

### Explanation of the formula

The formula is `Math.min(7, 31 - Math.clz32(i ^(i-1)))`.

- `i ^ (i-1)` gives the value when of all the binary 1-bits only the least significant remains and all others become zero.
- `Math.clz32` is a little known function that counts the leading zeroes (in 32-digit binary) of a given number.
- Subtracting that from 31 gives us the number of *trailing* zeroes.
- `Math.min(7, ...)` We want to get a number between 0 and 7 (trailing zeroes). This final step avoids an out of range value (which we would get for 0).